# Hide Tabs-Highlight on specific tab Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Given a set of tabs in Ionic 3 such as:

```
<ion-tabs tabsHighlight="true">
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="News" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Agenda" tabIcon="time"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Album" tabIcon="image"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The tabsHighlight attribute is set to true and that works perfect. However due to styling I want the little "highlight-strip" to disappear on a specific tab. Now I don't really care how it disappears, it may fade out or something. (It would actually be enough if it just became a couple pixel smaller in width.)

However since this element with the classes .tab-highlight and .animate is added by Ionic, I don't know how to access this element. Anywhere I look you access elements in Angular via the ViewChild, however, for that I would have to tag the element, e.g. with #my-ref, and I can't do that since it is added by Ionic.

Changing the tabsHightlight attribute does not work either. Apparently once this thing is rendered the attribute is not checked again. (As far as my tests have suggested.) Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set style for `tab-highlight` in `app.scss` but it is for the whole app. You can not do it for specific tab just in css. You need write some logic code:

In `tabs.html`:

```
<ion-tabs tabsHighlight="true">
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="News" (ionSelect)="showHighlight()" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Agenda" (ionSelect)="hideHighlight()" tabIcon="time"></ion-tab> //Assume that you want to hide tab-highlight in this tab
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Album" (ionSelect)="showHighlight()()" tabIcon="image"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In `tabs.ts`:

```
highlightElement: HTMLElement;
ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.highlightElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(".tabs .tab-highlight"); 
}
showHighlight(){
    if(this.highlightElement)
      this.highlightElement.style.display = "block";
}
hideHighlight(){
    if(this.highlightElement)
      this.highlightElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this worked. I also tried to animate the change but so far no luck on that one. It is however not my priority.

Answer (score 0):

If it generates class like `.tab-highlight` then you can access it.

*app.scss*

```
.tab-highlight{
   //give your change here
}
```

**Note:** Most of the time you need to use `!important` when you overrode the Ionic defaults.